# "Your login attempt was not successful. Please try again" in asp.net although password is reset

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, authentication, asp.net-membership

I have a problem with one account in asp.net, although I reset the password I still get this error when I am trying to login: "Your login attempt was not successful. Please try again"

How can I see the real message why this is happening? According to the database table for aspnet membership everything looks good:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put break point right at the very statement that authenticate your login information. Then debug and see if there's any exception. Remember to wrap with try..catch statement and put another breakpoint inside catch statement.

Answer (score 0):

I ran in this issue too.
After comparing with older versions of my project, I found the following issue.
The attribute:

```
onauthenticate="LoginSite_Authenticate"
```

was addad to the **asp:LoginView** control which caused this behavior.
After removing it - the login got back to mormal.